# Unsure of meaing of $T'(\lambda)$ in definition of simple eigenvalue?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, notation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory

Let $T:\Omega \subset \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^{m \times m}$ be a matrix-valued function. The number $\lambda \in \Omega$ is an eigenvector of $T$ if $T(\lambda)v = 0$, and $v\in\mathbb{C}^n$ is its corresponding eigenvector.

An eigenvalue $\lambda \in \Omega$ is called simple if
$$\text{Ker}(T(\lambda)) = \text{span}\{v\}, \quad v \neq 0, \quad T'(\lambda)v \notin R(T(\lambda).$$

It follows that, for the adjoint $T^H(z)$ we have that
$$\text{Ker}(T^H(\lambda)) = \text{span}\{w\}, \quad v \neq 0,$$
and
$$w^H T'(\lambda)v \neq 0.$$

**Question**

1. I'm not sure what's going on here as I don't know the notation $T'(\lambda)$ means. Is it the derivative? If so, how do we know that $T'(\lambda)v \notin R(T(\lambda)$?
2. Most importantly, where is the relation $w^H T'(\lambda)v \neq 0$ coming from?

**Edit**

This comes from page 4 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1580.pdf) paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be indeed $T'(\lambda)$ is the derivative. You don't know that $T'(\lambda)v\notin R(T(\lambda))$, this is a condition.

Note that $x\mapsto w^H$x has co-dimension one kernel. On the other hand $T(\lambda)$ has co-dimension one image, and $(T(\lambda)^Hw)^Hx=w^HT(\lambda)x=0$ for all $x$, so the kernel of $w^H$ must be the range of $T(\lambda)$. Since $T'(\lambda)v\notin R(T(\lambda))$ you have that $w^HT'(\lambda)v\neq0$.

Comment: But why is the condition $T'(\lambda)v \notin R(T(\lambda)$ needed to ensure $\lambda$ is a simple eigenvalue? I have never seen this condition for a simple eigenvalue before. This comes from page 4 of the following paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1580.pdf

Comment: I don't have any experience with this field. But I imagine the names of the definitions originally come from considering the case $T(\lambda)= A-\lambda\Bbb 1$. The context here may be some kind of moral generalisation of this case. Anyway, in this case you see that $T(\lambda)v=0\iff (A-\lambda\Bbb1)v=0\iff Av=\lambda v$ and $v$ really is an eigenvector of the matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. If $\lambda$ is not simple then either $\ker(\lambda\Bbb1 -A)$ is more than one dimensional or there exists a $w$ with $Aw=\lambda w+v$ (look at the Jordan normal form).